# Issues involving a function with an array (For task calculating matrix determinants)

Tags: arrays, performance, function, matrix, determinants

I'm having issues getting a function to work which should find the determinant of an upper triangular matrix. My code seems to return clearly incorrect values, usually zero and I'm pretty certain that this is caused by me defining the function incorrectly some how. I suspect it is a basic error on my part but after staring at it for sometime I havent managed to figure it out. Here is the function and printing code:

```
int Determinant(int mat[20][20],int N)
{
int X=0,Det=0;
    if (N==2){
              Det=mat[0][0]*mat[1][1]-mat[0][1]*mat[1][0];
              return(Det);
             }
    else {
             for(X = 0; X < N; X++){
             Det *= mat[X][X];

          }
         }
return (Det);
}
```

and the print function :

```
determinant=Determinant(matrix,n);
printf("Determinant = %d",determinant);
```

I'll include the full code that I've written so far to provide more detail. It's basic application at the moment is to define and n by n matrix (2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int determinant(int mat[20][20],int N);
int Determinant(int mat[20][20],int N)
{
int X=0,Det=0;
    if (N==2){
              Det=mat[0][0]*mat[1][1]-mat[0][1]*mat[1][0];
              return(Det);
             }
    else {
             for(X = 0; X < N; X++){
             Det *= mat[X][X];
          }
         }
return (Det);
}

int main()
{
    int n=0,i=1;
    printf("Please enter a number (n) between 2 and 4 to determine the dimensions of an (nxn) matrix \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

        while(n<2||n>4){
            printf("The value %d does not lie within the required range of 2-4, please re-enter \n",n);
            scanf("%d",&n);
            i++;
            if (i>=3){
                      printf("\nYou have entered invalid values 3 times. The programme has been terminated");
                      exit(0);
                     }
           }

    printf("\n(%dx%d) matrix selected\n",n,n);
    int matrix[n][n];


                int f,g=0;
                printf("Please enter matrix elements\n");
                    for(f=0;f<n;f++){

                        for(g=0;g<n;g++){
                            printf("Element[%d][%d] = ",f,g);
                            scanf("%d",&matrix[f][g]);
                        }
                    }

      int k,j;
      printf("\nThe matrix is\n");
      for(k=0;k<n;k++){
          printf("\n");
          for(j=0;j<n;j++){
              printf("%d\t",matrix[k][j]);
              }
           }



        int temp=0,c=0,determinant=0;
        float factor=0;
        k=0;
    /* Transform matrix into upper triangular */
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        /* Elementary Row Operation I */
        if(matrix[i][i] == 0)
        {
            for(k = i; k < n; k++)
            {
                if(matrix[k][i] != 0)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        temp = matrix[i][j];
                        matrix[i][j] = matrix[k][j];
                        matrix[k][j] = temp;
                    }
                k = n;
                }
            }
            c++;
        }
        /* Elementary Row Operation III */
        if(matrix[i][i] != 0)
        {
            for(k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                factor = -1.0 * matrix[k][i] /  matrix[i][i];
                for(j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    matrix[k][j] = matrix[k][j] + (factor * matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }



      printf("\nThe Upper triangular is\n");
      for(k=0;k<n;k++){
          printf("\n");
          for(j=0;j<n;j++){
              printf("%d\t",matrix[k][j]);
              }
           }

determinant=Determinant(matrix,n);
printf("Determinant = %d",determinant);


    /*
           */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `determinant==Determinant(matrix,n);` Do you mean `determinant = Determinant(matrix,n);`? The typo would cause determinant to hold only 1 or 0, and since you initialize determinant to 0, `<your function return value> == 0` is unlikely to be true. That would explain why your result is almost always 0.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the main issue, although I have now fixed this (I'll edit the code in the question to show this amendment) I continue to get determinant values of zero and other clearly incorrect values

Comment: Anyone have any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically the way you pass the matrix as a parameter. To see what I mean, change the definition of the function to read:

```
int Determinant(int mat[5][5],int N);
```

and instruct the function body to print the full 5x5 matrix passed:

```
int Determinant(int mat[5][5],int N)
{
    printf("\n");
    int a,b;
    for(a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for(b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mat[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int X=0,Det=0;

    Det = 1; // Add this too!
    for(X = 0; X < N; X++) {
        Det *= mat[X][X];
    }
    return (Det);
}
```

Now enter n=3 for the matrix dimension and pass the already upper triangular matrix

```
1 2 3
0 4 5
0 0 6
```

Observe the printout of the matrix passed in the Determinant() function, it will be something like this:

```
1       2       3       0       4                                                                                                                                                
5       0       0       6       0                                                                                                                                                
4196432 0       -163754450      0       -1253168992                                                                                                                              
32764   3       0       0       0                                                                                                                                                
3       0       0       0       3
```

This means that your array has been "reshaped", and your actual data are stored in  consecutive places in memory, unlike the original array.

TLDR: Although I am not very proficient with C, I think that you should define your 2d array as a dynamic one (for example using a double pointer).

PS: Don't forget to initialize Det variable to 1 instead of 0 in the function body, otherwise the product will always equal 0.